# Create private Button in Fragment-Class

Tags: android, button

I want to create my Buttons at the top of my class, but 
findViewById is not known, what do I need to change?

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btn_q_c_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_q_c_1);

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_launch, container, false);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
private Button btn_q_c_1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_launch, container, false);
    btn_q_c_1 = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.btn_q_c_1);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return rootView;
}
```

Assuming button belongs to `fragment_app_launch.xml` you inflate the layout and you need to look for the view in the current view hierarchy.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

> public final View findViewById (int id)
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Look for a child view with the given id. If this
>   view has the given id, return this view.
>
> Parameters id The id to search for.
>
> Returns The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null

Or in `onActivityCreated` use

```
btn_q_c_1 = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_q_c_1);
```

Comment: thanks! that works. can you do me a favor and explain to me what findViewById is? Is it a method of the View-Class? Is that why i have to use rootView.findViewById()?

Comment: @user3385402 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: @user3385402 yes its a method of view class you inflate a layout and the views belong to the inflated layout hence  `rootView.findViewById(intparam)`

Comment: hey, you seem to be very experienced. do you know whether I can submit a bundle with a clicked button? so if button 1 is clicked it passes an int with value 1 to the onclicklistener?

Comment: @Philip use bundle with intent to pass values between activities. But you don't need it just to access it in `OnClickListener` of the same Activity